# SQL Reporting Services - T2Embed.dll missing

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs

When generating a report in SSRS, I receive the following error:

```
There was an error generating your report. Please refer to item 673778174106859 for additional diagnostic information. There was an error during the render phase of the report generation. There was an error generating the document Network Statistics There was an error generating the document Network Statistics An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> 

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> 

Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.ReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> 

System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'T2Embed': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> 

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> 

Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.ReportRenderingException: An error occurred during rendering of the report. ---> 

System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'T2Embed': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Running a repair install of the specific SQL and RS instance did not help.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the DLL exist on the server? This occurs when generating any report?

Comment: I code-formatted the errors. I did not re-linefeed them.

Comment: Found this article... running some AV and malware scans just to be sure...  http://borepatch.blogspot.com/2011/11/emergency-security-workaround-from.html

Comment: @Shawn AV scans came back clean.  The DLL did exist at one point, however does not appear to be the case any longer.  Where can I re-aquire this DLL from?  When initially researching this issue, searching Google brings up a myriad of DLL download sites.  Are any of them reputable?

Comment: I would go to another SQL Server instance if you have access to one, or check the installation media for SQL Server.

Comment: @Shawn At this point, I think that would be best.  I've been researching this issue for a couple weeks now.  Even our vendor doesn't know what's going on.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: The other thing you might try, as last resort, would be to do a repair through the Add/Remove with Windows. it should just refresh the installation and not effect the reporting databases.

Comment: We're running Server 2008R2 Core, so unfortunately A/R Programs is not an option/availble in that edition.  We are migrating to a new VM instance with full Server 2008R2 Standard.

Comment: so you are running SQL Server on a unsupported OS?

Comment: Given that this is a Windows system file which was subject to a security update, wondering if it is a windows security update gone awry.  Either way I am puzzled as to why it was migrated here.  the poster's original idea of where this belonged may have been right.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Reporting Services specifically is [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231669.aspx) on Windows Server Core 2008 R2 SP1 and higher.

You've probably stumbled upon one of the reasons why it's not supported. (I.e., it flat out doesn't work.)

Besides hacking around, which may or may not actually fix the issue, I think your only recourse is to install SSRS on a full version of Windows Server, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to try if a DLL is missing.  The first is to search for it and if it is there, try running regsvr32 on it.  That may fix it as it corrects some registry entries sometimes required to load it.  This is one of the tricks I picked up working at Microsoft's PSS.

The second thing to do is to use Google and find out what software this DLL came with.  Then try reinstalling the appropriate program.  It looks like this is an issue with either Windows or a security update.  See http://www.ghacks.net/2011/11/04/microsoft-releases-critical-windows-security-update/

In that case you might try running sfc or similar.

The file, according to Google, is the open type embedded font engine.

Answer (score -1):

i think the best way to fixed this [dll missing](http://www.articlewritingclicks.com/errors/dll3.php) .. Try to download it manually from browse by Google...

Comment: Actually, that's a really bad idea!  DLL's can have malware injected into them.  Only official sources should be used!!!!